# C# - Как поменять разрешение захвата видео в Win10?

Tags: c#, изображения, windows-10, winrt

Я захватываю изображение с помощью:

```
VideoFrame currentFrame = await this.mediaCapture.GetPreviewFrameAsync();
_surface = currentFrame.Direct3DSurface;
```

Код, выложенный выше, работает. Но там я не могу поменять (ширину X высоту).

Если я поменяю выше выложенный код на:

```
VideoFrame videoFrame = new VideoFrame(BitmapPixelFormat.Yuy2, _width, _height);
VideoFrame currentFrame = await this.mediaCapture.GetPreviewFrameAsync(videoFrame);
_surface = currentFrame.Direct3DSurface;
SoftwareBitmap softBitmap = await SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromSurfaceAsync(_surface);
```

Выскакивает ошибка при создании SoftwareBitmap:

```
Исключение типа "System.AccessViolationException" возникло в App2.exe, 
но не было обработано в коде пользователя
Дополнительные сведения: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is
often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Я знаю, что для изменения используется MediaEncodingProfile, но использовать это можно лишь при записи видео в поток. А мой MediaCapture лишь выводит видео на CaptureElement, а не записывает.

Comment: Нашел несколько дней назад вот это: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15412772/take-photo-with-custom-resolution-from-captureelement-with-mediacapture